# Preventing mysqldump --databases from aborting if a database isn't found

Tags: mysql

I need to migrate a number of installations of a system that spans multiple databases. For background, each installation has a database for each module that is installed in that system. Not all installations have all modules installed.

Some of the module databases include views.

When I run `mysqldump --databases module1 module2 module3 > export.sql` (simplified command), it works fine on installations with all three modules installed. However, on an installation which doesn't have the module3 database, the views (and possibly other things) for module1 and module2 are not included in the export.

Is there a way I can run the `mysqldump` to dump complete database information for module1 and module2 even if the server does not have a module3 database,(other than by removing module3 from the mysqldump command)

Comment: I would try running multiple mysqldumps in serial for each database.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with only one password prompt (and without having the password in the command line)?

Comment: I would prompt for the password in the script and pass it on the command-line from the script.

Comment: Isn't that still the same security risk as passing it in on the command line directly?

Comment: Yes.  I can't think of any way around it.

Comment: Would it be possible to just dump the entire instance and import only what you need later?

Comment: I would then have to parse the dump to remove other databases that are not part of the system, unless there's a way to dump each database to a separate file. It is an option, but I'd like to avoid it, if possible.